# Как указать значения по условию для каждой группы?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, обработка-данных

Имеется фрейм данных:

```
data = {'фрукт': ['груша','огурец','вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша','арбуз','груша','банан', 'груша', 'вишня','яблоко', 'груша', 'вишня', 'абрикос', 'груша', 'банан'],
'страна': ['россия','сша', 'россия','россия', 'франция','ЮАР','франция', 'россия', np.nan,'россия','андорра', 'франция', 'португалия', 'россия', np.nan, 'россия'],
'id': ['01','01','01','02','02','03','03','011', '011', '011','011', '6', '6', '5', '5', '5'],
'месяц': ['март','январь','январь','март', 'сентябрь','март','октябрь', 'март', 'ноябрь', 'январь','январь', 'март', 'январь', 'март', 'июль', 'апрель']        
}
dates = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['фрукт','страна', 'id', 'месяц'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить новый фрейм, в котором для каждой группы `id` в колонке `месяц` указано значение месяца, которое следует после значения `"март"`. Если внутри группы нет других значений, но есть только `"март"` - оставить значения `"март"` для этой группы.

Как это сделать

Какой результат нужно получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def f(col, prev_val="март"):
    res = col[col.shift().eq(prev_val) & col.ne(prev_val)]
    if res.empty:
        return prev_val
    return res.iloc[0]

df["month_new"] = df["id"].map(df.groupby("id")["месяц"].apply(f))
```

результат:

```
In [60]: df
Out[60]:
      фрукт      страна   id     месяц month_new
0     груша      россия   01      март    январь
1    огурец         сша   01    январь    январь
2     вишня      россия   01    январь    январь
3   абрикос      россия   02      март  сентябрь
4     груша     франция   02  сентябрь  сентябрь
5     арбуз         ЮАР   03      март      март
6     груша     франция   03      март      март
7     банан      россия  011      март    ноябрь
8     груша         NaN  011    ноябрь    ноябрь
9     вишня      россия  011    январь    ноябрь
10   яблоко     андорра  011    январь    ноябрь
11    груша     франция    6      март    январь
12    вишня  португалия    6    январь    январь
13  абрикос      россия    5      март      июль
14    груша         NaN    5      июль      июль
15    банан      россия    5    апрель      июль
```

Comment: Если попытаться запустить это на фрейме , где в группе по id первое значение не "март", то группа примет значения "март", что неверно. Извините , что сразу не догадался о наличии таких примеров. Если первое значения не "март", то на всю группу нужно зафиксировать первое значение

Comment: @formanite, откройте новый вопрос и приведите в нем  __воспроизводимый__ пример данных и результат, который хотите получить. PS изменяя вопрос, на который уже дан ответ(ы), вы инвалидируете эти ответы

Answer (score 0):

Ребята, вы что, на одной овощебазе все работаете? Был уже такой вопрос,
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242489/срез-строк-внутри-группы-с-условием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1242489/%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Comment: это был мой вопрос и вопросы разные :)